# Is there a forum that specialises in Workflow Foundation?

Tags: workflow-foundation, forum

I know I can get answers here but I was wondering if anyone knows of a forum that specialises in WF as well as forums.asp.net for asp.net?

Comment: Just ask your question and people will try to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsworkflowfoundation/threads
2. forums.asp.net

Comment: I hadn't noticed the one on asp.net - thanks for that.
I'm not a big fan of the social.msdn.microsoft.com forums: they seem to have a major problem with their forum engines meaning loads of posts get duplicated.  And not always immediately, so you can be reading a thread and get several posts repeated and often not in order.  I'm surprised they haven't sorted it out: it feels like a scale-out problem and it reflects badly on MS, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

There is this one:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=54

but it's poor, and this associated:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Articles/ArticleListing.aspx?SectionID=1&SubSectionID=193